# Twitter Bootstrap button transition

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm experiencing a rather annoying conflict with Twitter Bootstrap.

When I mouse over a button the CSS transition only plays on hover out.

Here's my CSS:

```
@import url('http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css');

.container {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.btn-click-me {
    color: white !important;
    background: black !important;
    -webkit-transition: background linear 350ms;
}

.btn-click-me:hover {
    background: white !important;
}
```

A working JFiddle demo can be seen here: As seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/3805/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a specificity issue in `bootstrap.css` - by default all buttons have a transition - all you need to do is include the `.container` class in your selector and you'll override bootstrap and see the expected transition in both states. You can alternatively modify the default transition by going to line `3246` of bootstrap.css, the transition is on the `.btn:hover, .btn:focus` classes

The reason two classes overrides two classes in this case is because when using the `@import` conditional rule, the imported CSS precedes the CSS *you've* written in your jsFiddle. If two selectors have the same specificity the latest one declared in the stylesheet will win

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Misanthrope/MgcDU/3822/)

---

<sub>By two classes I'm referring to: `.container .btn-click-me` and `.btn:hover, btn:focus` which are equally specific</sub>

Answer (score 0):

if you want to review the transition on hover in and on hover out, add the transition even on the over state: http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/3821/

**CSS**

```
    @import url('http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css');

.container {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.btn-click-me {
    color: white;
     -webkit-transition: background linear 350ms;
    background: black;

}

.btn-click-me:hover {
 -webkit-transition: background linear 350ms;
    background: white ;
}
```